# Looking for a conversion rig or a swimmer rig

Tags: rigging, conversion

For a personal project I looking for a male and female swimmer fully rig.
I found some but for another software.

2 questions.
- is there someone who has these kind of caractor already done?
- is there someone interesting in doing a proper conversion?

Sure I know it's not free.
g.

Comment: Can you save them in .fbx or .obj?

Comment: Hello Josh, I don't have the rig at this moment. I have found one that I like: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/male-swimmer-female-3d-model-1153536